# oscillations with congestion sensitive routing

Tags: routes, dijkstra

Kurose in 'Computer Networking: top down approach' says if the link costs are equal to the amount of traffic carried(or delay or congestion) in the Link State algorithm the oscillation occurs. Author proposed not to use amount of traffic as link cost to avoid oscillation.
I wonder what are the other link cost parameters besides amount of traffic, congestion and delay that we can use as the link cost.

Comment: Are you asking what criteria can be used to labeled the arc costs between nodes, apart from traffic, delay and so on?

Comment: Exactly. This is my question.

Answer (score 0):

There's an inherent feedback condition that occurs when the metrics used in a link state algorithm are a direct function live utilization.  Path algorithms choose the least-utilized path -> said path becomes more utilized, path re-calculation uses alternate path -> initial path becomes less congested, rinse and repeat.

The options available are either to accept this oscillation and limit the frequency with which load-based recalculation occurs or to use alternate sources of metadata to inform path selection (ex: arbitrary link coloring, shared risk groups, etc).

In the former case (lengthening the period of oscillation) path optimization might be accomplished by re-weighting links (and re-calculating paths) based on some kind of 95th percentile average (for example) over a suitably long period of time - say days or weeks.  This is actually not far from what some traffic engineering and capacity planning groups do for larger service providers.  How the data is sampled and over what period of time varies widely, though.  It's also not commonly allowed without some degree of human oversight, although this is starting to change.

In the latter case (use of external metadata) link selection is going to be based on criteria that isn't necessarily directly visible at the network interface layer - examples might include affinity/anti-affinity groupings to allow for constrained SPF (nb: this tends to be a standard cost-based SPF application against an appropriately limited set of links).

For practical examples of other parameters in use I'd suggest taking a look at Cisco's implementation of its Enhanced Interior Gateway Routing Protocol ([EIGRP](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/ios-nx-os-software/enhanced-interior-gateway-routing-protocol-eigrp/whitepaper_C11-720525.html)), which actually incorporates **5** so-called K-values that can be considered for link selection, including: bandwidth, delay, link reliability, load and MTU.  Out of these only two (bandwidth and delay) are actually weighted for use in live path selection by default...much for the reasons mentioned (oscillation and resultant loss of determinism/stability).